# How to right align widget in horizontal linear layout Android?

Tags: android, alignment

This is the code I am using and it is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 487):

Try to add empty `View` inside horizontal `LinearLayout` before element that you want to see right, e.g.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />                

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works! But anyone can explain why? I couldn't totally understand.

Comment: Empty View is trying to take the maximum amount of space, leaving room for the button.

Comment: So far this has been the only thing that works for me in trying to have a few buttons on the left, and one final button on the right. But it feels like a hack to me. Is there a "right" way to do this?

Comment: This is awesome! But why gravity="right" does not work this way from the very beginning? Why does it need help from this other view? And how is it "right", if it is not, without the extra view?

Comment: This does not work in a grid-like layout - there is no empty space. Sherif elKhatib's solution works.

Comment: Using layout_weight is overkill for such simplistic task. Look at @Sherif elKhatib's answer. It is much better performance-wise.

Comment: work for me but make no sense lol, that's why I must use constraint

Answer (score 133):

Do not change the gravity of the LinearLayout to "right" if you don't want everything to be to the right.

Try:

1. Change TextView's **width** to `fill_parent`
2. Change TextView's **gravity** to `right`

Code:

```
    <TextView 
              android:text="TextView" 
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
              android:gravity="right">
    </TextView>
```

Comment: thanks for this - it was the width of fill_parent that was throwing me off

Comment: Is the linear layout even designed to achieve this? Shouldn't one just use the relative layout to achieve this? Is this solution not a hack?

Comment: this will not work if you have multiple TextView controls in a LinearLayout. See answer from @alcsan

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This approach does not use any additional views, and more importantly, it does not use layout_weight that considerably shows performance down.

Comment: `android:layout_weight = "1"` side by side with `android:gravity="right"`, should do the trick.

Comment: @Shantanu try this android:layout_gravity="right". It worked for me

Answer (score 81):

As a supplement to alcsan's answer, you can use `Space` since API 14 (Android 4.0 ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH), [document here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html).

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For apps that supporting API levels under 14, there is an [`android.support.v4.widget.Space`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/Space.html) since Android Support Library r22.1.0.

Comment: Important is that you need to set layout_weight = "1"

Comment: Works perfectly! Preserves the width of each element.

Comment: This works. Wow, Android's ugliness never ceases to amaze me

Comment: I'm not sure you even need the gravity attribute. I didn't. As long as you set the layout_weight of the Space element to 1, the Space takes up whatever horizontal space is left after the TextView gets whatever space it needs, which forces the TextView all the way to the right (since the Space comes before in the xml).

Comment: Android Studio now reports a warning when using a "Space" element in a LinearLayout
Replacing with a "View" element seems to fix the issue. In my case, I changed the layout to a ConstraintLayout, which also works fine

Answer (score 34):

With **Linear Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select_car_book_tabbar"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/my_booking_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

with **FrameLayout**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select_car_book_tabbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:src="@drawable/my_booking_icon" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

with **RelativeLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select_car_book_tabbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/my_booking_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 27):

setting the view's `layout_weight="1"` would do the trick.!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Such a simple solution +1

Comment: If someone is still looking, this is the right solution :)

Comment: This is Magic! How did you find it out?

Comment: @andreikashin, Consider a up vote if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a solution for components such as buttons

Answer (score 15):

Add `android:gravity="right"` to LinearLayout. Assuming the `TextView` has `layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: He specifically said to align a single component inside the LinearLayout. Not the linear layout itself : the layout itself is set to fill_parent.

Answer (score 11):

just add `android:gravity="right"` in your Liner Layout.

Answer (score 10):

For `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation, give `layout_weight` to other child view except for the view that you want to align right. This works perfectly.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Specialization"
                />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Right"
                android:textColor="#ff0000" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have done it by easiest way:

Just take one **RelativeLayout** and put your **child** **view** in it, which you want to place at **right** side.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f5f4f4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Hiren"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

`linear layout` with `layout_width="fill_parent"` and also the widget with same `layout width` + `gravity as right` would align it to the right.

I'm using 2 `TextView`s in following example, `topicTitle` on the left and `topicQuestions` on the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topicTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topicQuestions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No need to use any extra view or element:

//that is so easy and simple

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
>
```

//this is left alignment

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="No. of Travellers"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textAlignment="textStart"
      android:gravity="start" />
```

//this is right alignment

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Done"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textAlignment="textEnd"
      android:gravity="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a RelativeLayout and just drag them until it looks good :)

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_info"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pizza"
        android:src="@drawable/header_info_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "drag them" not recommended for multi resolution screen

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the layout_width to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` because `gravity:"right"` aligns the text inside the layout_width, and if you choose wrap content it does not have where to go, but if you choose match parent it can go to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Adding view  is bit difficult and it cover all screen width like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />                

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Try to this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Account"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case with TextView:

```
<TextView 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAlignment="gravity">    
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For aligning one element at start and one at the end of the `LinearLayout`, you can wrap it in an `RelativeLayout`.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Save"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

The result of this example is following:
[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuZjy.png)

Note: You can wrap whatever you want inside and align it.

Answer (score 0):

this is my xml, dynamic component to align right, in my case i use 3 button

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkinInputCodeMember">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bttn_extends"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="3"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bttn_checkout"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="2"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/checkinButtonScanQrCodeMember"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

and the result

you can hide the right first button with change visibility GONE, and this my code

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkinInputCodeMember">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bttn_extends"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="3"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bttn_checkout"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="2"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/checkinButtonScanQrCodeMember"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                **android:visibility="gone"**/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

still align right, after visibility gone first right component

[image: result code 1]

[image: result code 2]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample. the key to arrange is as follows

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Complete code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="abcd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spareName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="efgh" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use match_parent and gravity to set the TextView text to right, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="right" >



    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```