# How to align ImageButton to right in horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ImageButton` in `LinearLayout`. I try to put a `ImageButton` to right in horizontal `LinearLayout`. I use `layout_gravity="right"` but it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context="com.startsoft.musicalsound.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/img_bg_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_sort_by_size" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992804/how-to-right-align-widget-in-horizontal-linear-layout-android

Comment: Is there a need for layout nesting? Why don't you use `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:gravity="right"` on the parent layout of your `ImageButton`. You can also remove `android:layout_gravity="right"` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the gravity of button to right like this:
android:layout_gravity="right"